# Changing an arraylist method to a linkedlist method

Tags: java, linked-list

I have an arraylist method that I need to change to a linkedlist method. It's throwing a `nullpointerexception` at the int x line.It is throwing at another nullpointerexception to another line. But that line is where the method is called. Below is the code:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at PlantList.analyzePlants(PlantList.java:303)
  at PlantList.main(PlantList.java:434)


 private void analyzePlants() {
          String text = "";

          Node p = root;
          while(p!=null) {
              text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the string to analyze: " );

           int x = analyze(p.plant.getName().toLowerCase(), analyzeText.getText().toLowerCase());
           text += p.plant.getName() + " : " + x + "\n";
           p =p.next;
          }
          JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(text);
          JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
          textArea.setLineWrap(true);
          textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
          scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 300));
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane, "Analyzation Completed",   JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
          analyzeText.setText("");
           p = p.next;
    }
    /**
     * Recursive function to analyze the plants in the system.
     */
    private int analyze(String name, String text) {
          if (!name.contains(text)) {
           return 0;
          }
          if (name.startsWith(text)) {
           return 1 + analyze(name.substring(1), text);
          } else {
           return 0 + analyze(name.substring(1), text);
          }
         }
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message also.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PlantList.analyzePlants(PlantList.java:303)
 at PlantList.main(PlantList.java:434) Line 303 is the int x and line 434 is the call to the method.

Comment: So line 303 is the `int x` line, is it??

Answer (score 0):

> It's throwing a nullpointerexception at the int x line

Either `p.plant` , `p.plant.getName()`, `analyzeText` or `analyzeText.getText()` is/are null.

**Updated** Before calling any method on analyze text perform null check. E.g.

```
String param1 = p.plant.getName().toLowerCase()
String param2 = "";//you can also initialize to null
if(analyzeText != null && analyzeText.getText() != null) {param2 = analyzeText.getText().toLowerCase()}
int x = analyze(param1, param2);
```

Comment: How do I find out which one is null. I am kinda new.

Comment: @Beth you can use debugger or before `int x=...` add `System.out.println(p.plant);` `System.out.println(p.plant.getName());` `System.out.println(p.plant.analyzeText);` `System.out.println(p.plant.analyzeText.getText());` which ever print null is/are causing the Exception

Comment: Thanks I will check it out and see which one it is.

Comment: analyzeText is causing the problem. How do I resolve it?

Comment: @Beth you can add the `null` check before calling any method on `analyzeText`.

Comment: analyzetext is a JTextField. Can that be null?